# Deep linking to nested screens in react navigation v5 for react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a `StackNavigator` nested inside a `DrawerNavigator`. I can't seem to link to screens nested inside the `StackNavigator`. For instance, given this nav structure:

```
export default class Navigator extends Component {
  Posts = () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Index" headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={PostIndexScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Show" component={PostShowScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="New" component={PostNewScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Reply" component={PostNewReplyScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="JustPublished" component={PostPublishedScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }

  Home = () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Posts" component={this.Posts} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }

  render = () => {
    const Main = createDrawerNavigator()
    return <NavigationContainer linking={{
      prefixes: ["myapp://"],
      config: {
        screens: {
          Home: {
            path: "",
            screens: {
              Posts: "posts",
            },
          },
        },
      }
    }}>
      <Main.Navigator
        drawerStyle={{ width: 0 }}
        initialRouteName={"Home"}
      >
        <Main.Screen name="Home" component={this.Home} />
      </Main.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  }
}
```

The following link should take you to the `Posts` screen inside `Home`:

```
Linking.openURL("myapp://posts")
```

However it stays at the `Home` screen. I've already tried setting a non-empty pathname to `Home` and doing something like `Linking.openURL("myapp://home/posts")` to no avail.

The only way I could make it work is by putting all of the `Post` screens at the same level as `Home` right inside the `DrawerNavigator`. This would already be a quick fix, but the actual app structure requires me to navigate to the `Posts` section from several other screens mounted at the `DrawerNavigator` right beside `Home` and being able to `goBack()` to said screens, so a top-level `Posts` screen doesn't quite cut it.

My desired structure is basically something like:

```
- Home
  -- FeaturedArticle
    -- Comments
      -- Comment
  -- ArticlesList
    -- Article
      -- Comments
        -- Comment
```

Comment: You have 2 screens named "Home", one in drawer, one in stack. Did you try changing that?

Comment: Did you got the solution? I have something similar in my app

Answer (score 0):

Here I am attaching snip of my code so that you can have a idea to archive this thing in your case

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['myDemoApp://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        MyStack1: {
          path: 'MyStack1/:id?',
          parse: {
            id: id => `${id}`,
          },
        },
        MyStack2: {
          screens: {
            Stack22: 'Stack22/:id?',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```